# How to catch NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, xml, exception

I am trying to  Deserialize XML file containing methods.
Snippet looks like:

```
 XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder(os); 
    deSerializedObject = decoder.readObject(); 
    decoder.close();
    return deSerializedObject;
```

When XML file does not contain method for every object.It throws NoSuchMethodException @ readObject.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No method with name add is found
>        at java.beans.Statement.findMethod(Statement.java:454)
>       at java.beans.Statement.invokeMethodImpl(Statement.java:247)
>       at java.beans.Statement.access$000(Statement.java:46)
>       at java.beans.Statement$1.run(Statement.java:130) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:284)
>       at java.beans.Statement.invokeMethod(Statement.java:127)
>       at java.beans.Expression.getValue(Expression.java:67)    at java.beans.XMLDecoder$SAXHandler.executeCommon(XMLDecoder.java:392)
>       at java.beans.XMLDecoder$SAXHandler.execute(XMLDecoder.java:321)
>       at java.beans.XMLDecoder$SAXHandler.endElement(XMLDecoder.java:286)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown
>   Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown
>   Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown
>   Source)
>        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>   at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source)  at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)  at java.beans.XMLDecoder.readObject(XMLDecoder.java:662)

Problem is I can not catch this exception. What is the proper way to handle it?

```
try{
        deSerializedObject = decoder.readObject();
        System.out.println("We are after read object");
        }
        catch (NoSuchMethodException e)
        {
            System.out.println("We are in catch block !!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        decoder.close();
        return deSerializedObject;
```

Here error is "Unreachable catch block for NoSuchMethodException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body"

XML Looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<java version="1.6.0" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
 <object class="java.util.ArrayList">
  <void method="add">
   <object class="InfoParameters">
    <void property="Name">
     <string>Jay</string>
    </void>
     <void property="Level">
     <string>10</string>
    </void>
   </object>
   <object class="InfoParameters">
    <void property="Name">
     <string>Hir</string>
    </void>
    <void property="Level">
     <string>10</string>
    </void>
   </object>
  </void>
 </object>
</java>
```

Comment: Oh I see, since `readObject()` isn't declared to throw a `NoSuchMethodException` Java doesn't think that one is likely to happen, try adding a default exception block after the `NoSuchMethodException` one. I'll add it to my post below.

Comment: There has to be something else going on in code that you haven't posted. According to the error message `readObject()` isn't the root cause of the exception, so it must be coming from a different statement

Comment: Can you post the XML version of the serialized object? There has to be something going on there.

Comment: @Hunter Added the XML version.

Answer (score 3):

Why can't you catch this exception?

```
XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder(os); 

try
{
    deSerializedObject = decoder.readObject(); 
}
catch(NoSuchMethodException nsme)
{
    System.err.println(nsme.getMessage());
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //try me
}

decoder.close();
return deSerializedObject;
```

Comment: When I put try {NoSuchMethoException} catch {} block, Compiler says Unreachable catch block for NoSuchMethodException. And with try {Exception} catch simply does not catch.

Comment: can you post what you tried to do? Because what you are saying doesn't make sense

Comment: Can you post it in your question?, the comment makes it very hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason "catch (Exception e)" is not working try:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (Throwable t) {
    ...
}
```

This should catch every possible exception and error, since it's the base class for all exceptions.

Comment: You should never do that. It may result in very hard to find bugs.

Comment: It should only done if you really know what you are doing.
He could also do:
    catch (Throwable t) {
        if (!(t instanceof NoSuchMethodException)) {
            throw t;
        }
    }